# Python how to check if a string represent a float?

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I'm developing a small menu in python where at some point the user is being asked for a float number.

The user could pass:

```
1.23
1 //it's valid...
23.34e-10 //scientific notation
```

The user is asked for inserting a float value, if the value is not a float (for example the user could write a generic string...) the program doesn't have to crash but just to re-iterate until the user pass a valid float value. So actually the structure is

```
var = "";
while(var is not a float):
   var = raw_input("");
```

Does exists a fast way to do that? or should use somehow a regular expression?

Comment: Most of them deal with try - except blocks... it's not what i want.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Comment: Why don't you want to use try - except? Exceptions in Python are quite efficient, and if the exception isn't raised a `try: ... except` is faster than an equivalent `if`. Of course, efficiency is irrelevant when you're waiting for user input in the terminal. :)

Comment: Because for what i'm doing i don't want the program terminate... is not a matter of efficiency. I mean i usually use try-except block for intermediate computation... not for input provided by the user by a menu.

Comment: Using try-except won't make the program terminate. See the first example in the accepted answer on the page I linked. That code uses try-except to test for a valid `int` but it's easy to adapt it to validate a `float`.

Comment: You right... i didn't know that.

Comment: If you want to know how to do this without try-catch, re-ask the question with that condition, and I can answer with a regular expression that captures valid FP strings.